# how do i install tl-WN727N linux driver ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, 23.04, tp-link

when i was installing ubuntu 23.10 it automatically installed some ralink drivers how do i change it to tplink drivers? and when i'm blacklisting ralink driver wifi doesnt work.

```
lsusb gives me this:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter



kr1ner@Kr1nerPC:~/Documents/rtl8188eu$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-17-generic/build M=/home/kr1ner/Documents/rtl8188eu modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-17-generic'
```

Comment: Why do you want to replace the driver? Is there any problem with the one that was installed automatically?

Comment: yes its way too slow than windows

Comment: Where did the content of `~/Documents/rtl8188eu` come from? Was it advertised as a driver for your TL-WN727N device? Did it come with installation instructions? Did you follow them? At which point of them did you encounter a problem?

Comment: i tried company's tutorial and other users tutorial which had same problem and it worked for them but they had older ubuntu versions.

Comment: does anyone have idea how to fix it?

Comment: The driver for your device is *rt2800usb*. Compiling and installing rtl8188eu will do nothing at all. I suggest that you look elsewhere, such as the router settings. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` Only show your router and redact the SSID with XXXX.

Comment: first of all thanks for commenting. so i have TL-WN727N adapter and my pc automatically downloaded some ralink drivers rt2800usb , when i was trying to install the tplink driver i found out that my kernel version is newer and doesnt support that software so any idea how i can install it without going back to old kernel or how should i change it back to old kernel either idk elaborate

Comment: The driver you are trying to install *rtl8188eu*, is wrong for your device. It won't work. Ever. Since it won't load and drive your device, it can't and won't make it faster.

Comment: then what should i do doctor? is there anything i can do?

Comment: but the adapter resets every 2 seconds and refreshes .

Comment: and starts searching for network

Comment: Let's see a complete diagnostic report, please: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: It sounds like you may have a power issue on USB if the adapter "refreshes"